# Is there an equivalent of the "MediaPlayerConnectivity" Firefox extension for Chrome?

Tags: firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions, video-streaming, video-playback

The [MediaPlayerConnectivity](https://addons.mozilla.org/bg/firefox/addon/mediaplayerconnectivity/) extension allows an easy way to play DivX and other streaming videos in external applications (like VLC).

Is there something like this for Chrome?

I want to play videos in an external player thus not relying on browser crashes and performance.

Answer (score 0):

SVPTube performs the same function but it is not a Chrome extension